# .Net WebApi returns Jsons with formats other than the development environment

Tags: c#, .net, json.net, asp.net-web-api2

We have a WebApi that simply returns a JSON response like this:

> [{ "company": "KYC" }]

When we publish the WebApi, using the publish option on VS or just copying and paste on the server, it returns this very weird, and it's only on this server.

The response on the production server is:

> {    "Version": {
>         "_Major": 1,
>         "_Minor": 1,
>         "_Build": -1,
>         "_Revision": -1    },    "Content": {
>         "Headers": [
>            {
>               "Key": "Content-Type",
>               "Value": [
>                  "application/json; charset=utf-8"
>               ]
>            }
>         ]    },    "StatusCode": 200,    "ReasonPhrase": "OK",    "Headers": [],    "RequestMessage": null,    "IsSuccessStatusCode":
>   true }

I already "Googled" this with no success.
Here is the controller code:

```
    [Authorize]
    [HttpGet]
    [EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
    [Route("api/Infra/GetEmpresas/{system}")]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetCompanies(string system)
    {
        logger.Debug("Start GetCompanies");
        HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
        try
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(system))
            {
                Companies comps = new Companies();
                var result = comps.GetCompanies(system);

                if (result != string.Empty)
                {
                    if (result.ToLower().StartsWith("error"))
                    {
                        response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
                        response.Content = new StringContent(
                            "{\"error\":\"" + result + "\"}", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        response.Content = new StringContent(
                        result, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
                    response.Content = new StringContent(
                        "{\"error\":\"Company not found\"}", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
                response.Content = new StringContent(
                    "{\"error\":\"System was not provided\"}", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exx)
        {
            logger.Error("Error on GetCompanies");
            logger.Error(exx);
            response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
            response.Content = new StringContent(
                "{\"error\":\"Error on GetCompanies\"}", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        }
        return response;
    }
```

Comment: the return JSON object looks good to  me , what does it look like on other servers?

Comment: @kapmirch The returned JSON is this:{ "Version": { "_Major": 1, "_Minor": 1, "_Build": -1, "_Revision": -1 }, "Content": { "Headers": [ { "Key": "Content-Type", "Value": [ "application/json; charset=utf-8" ] } ] }, "StatusCode": 200, "ReasonPhrase": "OK", "Headers": [], "RequestMessage": null, "IsSuccessStatusCode": true }

Comment: Yes @kapmirch. It's driving us crazy here. Obviously is something on this server, but we can't find the cause. Even the web.config is the same on development environment.

Comment: from a quick look at the code it seems you're directly logging the returned content. but i don't see the param for "company" in the response, so you need to get the resolved value with then or await.

Comment: @kapmirch the result variable has the text of the GetCompanies method, in wich I return the serialized value from an array of string. 
var result = comps.GetCompanies(system);
As I said, on other machines everything goes fine, only on this one, and the most important, I receive this response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for my case was very simple. Just updated the framework to latest .Net version, in this case, 4.8.
The server that we were having the problem was 4.6.1586.

Comment: that is great !! good to know. i was going to ask you to check connectionString and if it was set for  the server. But it sounded like you knew what you were doing. i am happy that you got it resolved. crazy how something so simple can cause you to rethink everything you have done.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried generating the HttpResponseMessage using the CreateResponse/CreateErrorResponse methods of the Request?

```
[Authorize]
    [HttpGet]
    [EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
    [Route("api/Infra/GetEmpresas/{system}")]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetCompanies(string system)
    {
        logger.Debug("Start GetCompanies");
        HttpResponseMessage response;
        try
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(system))
            {
                Companies comps = new Companies();
                var result = comps.GetCompanies(system);

                if (result != string.Empty)
                {
                    if (result.ToLower().StartsWith("error"))
                    {
                        response = Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, result);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        response = Request.CreateResponse(result);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    response = Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "Company not found");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                response = Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "System was not provided");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exx)
        {
            logger.Error("Error on GetCompanies");
            logger.Error(exx);
            response = Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, "Error on GetCompanies");
        }
        return response;
    }
```